# CoreData optimization for big data

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data

The fetching request inside the block taking around 9 minutes to process checked on instrument customerArray has around 60K objects and    CusCustomerAddress Model has around 30k objects so I have to optimise this time.

```
   NSArray *customerArray=[engine getItemsForEntity:@"CusCustomer" predicate:nil error:nil];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"id1 == $idVar"]];
        NSPredicate *predicateCustomerAddress = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"customerId == $customerIdVar AND addressType == $addressTypeVar"]];

    [customerArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CusCustomer *customer, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {            
        NSString *customerId=customer.id1;
        NSString *addressType = ShippingAddress;
        NSDictionary *variablesAddress = @{ @"customerIdVar" : customerId , @"addressTypeVar" : addressType};
        NSArray *resultAddress = [engine getItemsForEntity:@"CusCustomerAddress" predicate:[predicateCustomerAddress        predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variablesAddress] error:nil];
        if (resultAddress.count == 1 ) {
            [customer addCustomerAddressObject:(CusCustomerAddress *)[resultAddress lastObject]];
        }
        else
        {
            DLogHp(@"More than one tuple Exist For  this'id1' =\"%@\" in \"CusCustomerGroup\"",objId);
        }
        addressType = BillingAddress;
        NSDictionary *variablesAddress1 = @{ @"customerIdVar" : customerId , @"addressTypeVar" : addressType};

        NSArray *resultaddress1 = [engine getItemsForEntity:@"CusCustomerAddress" predicate:[predicateCustomerAddress predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variablesAddress1] error:nil];

        if (resultaddress1.count == 1 ) {
            [customer addCustomerAddressObject:(CusCustomerAddress *)[resultaddress1 lastObject]];
        }
        else
        {
            DLogHp(@"More than one tuple Exist For  this'id1' =\"%@\" in \"CusCustomerGroup\"",objId);
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: Wow, what are you trying to do ? If you are displaying this data, use NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: A `NSFetchedResultsController` is for views, this is data processing and a `NSFetchedResultsController` won't solve anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is probably the most expensive way possible to retrieve data from Core Data (or any database for that matter).  You are effectively creating N fetches as opposed to building a single query.

Consider changing your logic to something like:

1. Get customerIDs via KVC into an array:

   NSArray *ids = [customerArray valueForKey:@"id1"];
2. Fetch all shipping addresses for those customers with a predicate like:

   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"addressTypeVar == %@ && customerIdVar IN %@", ShippingAddress, ids];
   NSArray *shippingResults = ...;
3. Turn the results of that fetch into a dictionary based on customerID

   NSDictionary *shippingAddresses = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:shippingResults forKeys:[shippingResults valueFOrKey:@"customerIdVar"];
4. Iterate over your customer array and associate shipping addresses:

   for (id customer in customerArray) {
     [customer addCustomerAddressObject:[shippingAddresses[customer.id1]]];
   }
5. Repeat for business address

I have to say though, this is rather backwards.  Ideally you should be creating these relationships when you are importing or creating the data.  Doing it after the data is already in the store is inefficient.

A few other points:

- If a method returns `id` you do not need to cast it.  The cast just adds noise, remove it.
- Your variable names rough.  I would suggest removing the "Var" as it is redundant
- Consider fetching in batches as this procedure is going to cause you some significant memory problems.  60K records is going to be expensive no matter what.
- When doing a predicate, go cheap to expensive.  Right now you have string compares in your predicate.  That is the most expensive.  If you can change your data model, change your address types to integers.  Number comparison is far cheaper.

Comment: thanks Marcus S. Zarra I need a to know one more question please have a look on it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321420/addrelationship-to-only-updated-products-core-data