# addrelationship to only updated products Core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have around 1 lac products in the context, but when I synchronise to server only 10-15 product is update so I have to update the relationship of the product also with other models.

So is there any method that I can get the updated products only from the Core data file or the context.
Its very time consuming to make all relationship again of 1 lac products.

I checked InsertedObject property but it give me 0 after saving context.

Comment: What is causing you to have to fix all the relationships? You need to give more details on the model and your code.

Comment: actually Product model is related to other model like taxCode model so  If I get a new product or some product code is updated then I have to reestablish the relationship for that product is there any method so that I can get only the recent updated objects from the context.

Comment: Only if you tag them or get the objects before you save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving us much detail to work with.  You are getting 10-15 products from the server and are parsing them into Core Data?

If that is what you are doing then it is during the parse that you should be doing any relationship mapping.  You have all the information you need during the parse so that is the proper time to be doing any other maintenance or mapping.

If that is not the issue then update your question with more detail.